# Git conflicts between two protected branches

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

So I have three branches in total `deploy` `release` and `main`

Each of this represents a environment to be deployed on

```
Branches:     deploy --> release --> main 
Environments: dev        uat         PROD
```

Now the `dev` branch is a non-protected branch, means you can push and do all sort of stuff on it

But my `release` and `main` branches are protected branches which only accepts merges from other branch

Whenver I have problems when merging from `dev` to `release` I can directly commit the changes to the `dev` branch
Problem is that whenever I do `release` to `main` I get conflicts which I can't directly commit to `release`

Could anyone suggest how I work with this

If it helps, this is on GitLab

Thanks in advance

I searched online that you should create another branch through `release`, and then merge `main` into `release` and fix the conflicts

But the moment I go to merge this new branch to `release` it doesn't show me any changes (Reason being that always the lower branches would have the updated code)

And after that I would assume that my Merge Request would be deployed but that is still blocked

Answer (score 0):

Create an unprotected work branch, and solve your merge conflicts in that branch.

Here is an illustration for the "merge `main` into `release`" action:

1. create a work branch from `release`:

```
git checkout -b merge-main-into-release release
```

2. merge `main` into that branch:

```
git merge main
```

fix the conflicts in that work branch

3. push that work branch to your remote

```
git push origin merge-main-into-release
```

4. open a merge request to merge this branch into `release`

that merge request should be ok -- i.e: no conflicts there.